# PowerShell match, contains doesn't work with network share paths

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to identify drive name of mapped network share with Root like

> \\SERVER05\DIR$

This simply doesn't work:

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object {$_.Root -like "SERVER05" }
```

tried with `-match`, `-contains` and nothing

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is one of those PowerShell Gotchas. The default properties returned for PSDrives is Name, Description, Provider, Root and Current Location. Lets look at my M drive for example

```
Get-PSDrive -Name M

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                               CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                               ---------------
M                 769.66        112.47 FileSystem    \\s5000\Computer Srv\Matt
```

Problem you are having is that while you see the name of `Root` when you send it to default output stream you are actually looking at the value of `DisplayRoot`. It's misleading but the information you want is still there.

```
Get-PSDrive -Name M | Format-List *

Used            : 826416230400
Free            : 120764563456
CurrentLocation : 
Name            : M
Provider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
Root            : M:\
Description     : 
Credential      : System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
DisplayRoot     : \\s5000\Computer Srv\Matt
```

This is something handled behind the scenes with PowerShell formatting xml files. Specifically this comes from a line in PowerShellCore.format.ps1xml which defines the value for `Root` as `DisplayRoot` if it has a value... otherwise `Root`

```
<TableColumnItem>
    <ScriptBlock>if($_.DisplayRoot -ne $null) { $_.DisplayRoot } else { $_.Root }</ScriptBlock>
</TableColumnItem>
```

---

If you have kept up with me so far..

It was trying to do you a favour by showing you want you likely wanted to see. Knowing that... try filtering on `DisplayRoot` instead.

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object {$_.DisplayRoot -like "*SERVER05*" }
```

Don't forget to use asterisks when using `-like` when you are trying to do a partial match.  When in doubt examine your objects with cmdlets list `Format-List`, `Get-Member` and `Select-Object` to see more information.